# google-charts arrayToDataTable from ajax json

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, google-visualization

i want to create google-charts using data from ajax

```
var genres = $.ajax({
   async: false,
   url: "includes/ajaxproject.php",
   global: false,
   dataType: "json",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
      bar: true
   }
   }).responseText;
```

the variable has this value: ["Year", "Movies", "Shows"],[2016,0,185],[2017,0,378],[2018,0,553],[2019,36,662],[2020,82,775],[2021,114,544]

but when i use the variable, using this code:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(genres);
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([obj]);
```

it shows error like this: **Unexpected token , in JSON at position 30 at JSON.parse ()**

how can i use the variable as the data for the visualization?

Comment: Value is already array so you don't need to parse it from json. Just put genres to data table.

Comment: @elmasterlow i've tried it before, and it shows error like this: ** Error: Column header row must be an array.**

Comment: @elmasterlow the variable became like this: [,",Y,e,a,r,",,, ,",M,o,v,i,e,s,",,, ,",S,h,o,w,s,",],,,[,2,0,1,6,,,0,,,1,8,5,],,,[,2,0,1,7,,,0,,,3,7,8,],,,[,2,0,1,8,,,0,,,5,5,3,],,,[,2,0,1,9,,,3,6,,,6,6,2,],,,[,2,0,2,0,,,8,2,,,7,7,5,],,,[,2,0,2,1,,,1,1,4,,,5,4,4,]

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse('[' + genres + ']');
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([obj]);`

Comment: `arrayToDataTable` is a static method, don't need `new` keyword. and if `obj` is an array, then don't need brackets here --> `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(obj);`